# Why doesn't my query use my criteria?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a db in Access and I'm trying to get a textbox to run my query and pass an other bounded textbox's value in as the criteria in `DLookUp`.  I have the query running in design view and when I enter the criteria directly it returns the correct results. When I open the report it gives me the sum of all the possible rows. In other words it doesn't filter the rows.

I haven't used Access in about twelve years, *thankfully*, and everything I've done up to this point has been tutorial/example patchwork, but here it is...

SQL Query:

```
SELECT Sum(IIf(Attended=-1,1,0)) AS attendance
FROM Students_Classes_Attendance
WHERE (((CStr([Students_Classes_Attendance].[Class_Id]))=[classId]));
```

DLookUp as Control Source:

```
=DLookUp("[Total Attendance by Class]![attendance]",
         "[Total Attendance by Class]",
         "[Class_Id] =" & [Class_Id])
```

I'm lost at the moment. I'm guessing that the value isn't there before the query fires and since the criteria is an optional parameter that it's being passed null, but I would hope you'd get an error from that. Not that `#Error` is very meaningful anyway.

Does anyone know for certain the problem and the best way to correct it? Thanks.

**Edit:**
I did the changes recommended in the answer so now my `DLookUp` looks like...

```
=DLookUp("[attendance]",
         "[Total Attendance by Class]",
         "[Class_Id] =" & [Class_Id])
```

...still returns the total for all rows.  Removing the criteria completely makes no difference either, which returns me to thinking it has something to do with the bound textbox not having a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DLookup uses the following syntax:

1. **Syntax for numerical values:**

   DLookup("FieldName" , "TableName" , "Criteria = n")
2. **Syntax for strings: (note the single apostrophe before and after the string value)**

   DLookup("FieldName" , "TableName" , "Criteria= 'string'")
3. **Syntax for dates: (note the # before and after the date value)**

   DLookup("FieldName" , "TableName" , "Criteria= #date#")

I believe you just need to remove the table name from the first parameter.  Try this:

```
=DLookUp("[attendance]", "[Total Attendance by Class]", "[Class_Id] = " & [Class_Id])
```

Keep in mind that if Class_Id is a Text Field, you need to surround it by single quotes:

```
=DLookUp("[attendance]", "[Total Attendance by Class]", "[Class_Id] = '" & [Class_Id] & "'")
```

Comment: Thanks, it didn't change the report unfortunately. It makes sense that I wouldn't need the table name because the query design knows about it. So you don't think it could be a matter of the textbox it gets the criteria, which gets loaded from a table, might not be there when the query gets called? The report is the same if I remove the criteria part all together.

Comment: Slap in a **MsgBox "The Class ID is " & [Class_Id] & ""** just before the DLookUp statement and see what it thinks that variable is.

Comment: I hope my machine makes it through my frustration. Now even if I copy/paste what was working off the post, which I copied straight from Access, results in an #Error. The query still works fine directly but not in the report. When I tried to add your tidbit it said there were syntax errors with - possible operator without operand.

Comment: I'm a little confused about your exact process, so let me just ask: do you (or can you) pass the value of the textbox into your query **before** you open the report?  If it's a static query used for nothing but this report, you might consider building the filter right into the query.  To do that, you would put the value of the textbox into the Criteria row in the query (when you open it in Design View).  Just put something like, [Forms]![MyForm].[MyTextbox] and it will filter based on what's in the textbox.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me; that was it.